# Calculating the integral of some bessel function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

How can I calculate$$\int \frac {x\left(J_{ \frac 34}(\frac {x^2}{2})-J_{- \frac 54}(\frac {x^2}{2})\right)}{2J_{- \frac 14}(\frac {x^2}{2})}dx~?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some recurrence formulas that you can maybe use in this case:
$$J_{n+1}(x)-J_{n-1}(x)=-2J'_n(x)$$
Since $n+1=\frac 3 4\implies n=-\frac 14$
And
$$n-1=-\frac 5 4$$
So you have :
$$J_{3/4}(x)-J_{-5/4}(x)=-2J'_{-1/4}(x)$$
And for the integral:
$$
\begin{align}
I=&\int \frac {x\left(J_{ \frac 34}(\frac {x^2}{2})-J_{- \frac 54}(\frac {x^2}{2})\right)}{2J_{- \frac 14}(\frac {x^2}{2})}dx \\
I=&-\int \frac x{J_{- \frac 14}(\frac {x^2}{2})} \frac {dJ_{-\frac 14}(x^2/2)}{d \frac {x^2}2}dx\\
I=&-\int \frac {dJ_{- \frac 14}(\frac {x^2}{2})}  {J_{-\frac 14}(\frac {x^2}{2})}\\
I=&-\ln \left ( J_{- \frac 14}(\frac {x^2}{2}) \right )
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That last sentence made me a little nauseous haha. Good work with the Bessel function identities. They're incredibly useful.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks. I made a mistake the integral can be evaluated nicely because the Bessel function is taken for $x^2/2$ so the derivative in the recurrence formula is nice.

Comment: Indeed, very nice use of the identity! Don’t you want to complete the problem by evaluating the integral then? As you say, everything works out nicely...

Comment: @AndrasVanyolos you mean it's not nice ? I mean in the recurrence formula its $dJ(u)/du=dJ(x^2)/dx^2$ It should simplify the integral and cancel the x at the denominator

Comment: It is nice, i like it!

Comment: Ok @AndrasVanyolos I like it too.

Comment: Exactly, that’s the final answer to OP’s question.

Comment: Thanks @AndrasVanyolos I completed my answer now.